# Column left alignment issue - mobile only

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am running into an alignment issue on iphone where my column section is left aligning. It works fine on desktop and android. I am not sure what the issue is. Thanks

```css
  .column {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
```

```html
<!---- Steps Section ---->
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 600px; background-color:#ffffff;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="column" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 33%;">
        <h4 style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">STEP ONE
        </h4>
        <p style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; ">You’ve got your savings
          <br /> card ready to go.
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="column" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 33%;">
        <h4 style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">STEP ONE
        </h4>
        <p style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; ">You’ve got your savings
          <br /> card ready to go.
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="column" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 33%;">
        <h4 style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">STEP ONE
        </h4>
        <p style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; ">You’ve got your savings
          <br /> card ready to go.
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to get mobile to center align like desktop does. Right now there is a large grey space to the right of all 3 columns on mobile only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
     .column {text-align: left !important;}
   }

In addition, `:after` doesn't work in most email clients. It might be something to avoid if you're using it for major css structure elements.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your code. I changed float, width and added display to your `column` class.

Note, if you want to overwrite anything using media queries and its already present inline, you need to use `!important` in your CSS to do it.

```css
 .column {
        float: left;
      }
@media only screen and (max-width:600px){
        .column {
          float: none !important;
          width: 100% !important;
   display:inline-block;
          margin: 0px;
        }
}
```

```html
<!---- Steps Section ---->      
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="max-width: 600px; background-color:#ffffff;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="column" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 33%;">
              <h4 style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">STEP ONE
              </h4>
              <p style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; ">You’ve got your savings
                <br />
                card ready to go.
              </p>
            </td>
            <td class="column" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 33%;">
              <h4 style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">STEP ONE
              </h4>
              <p style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; ">You’ve got your savings
                <br />
                card ready to go.
              </p>              
            </td>
            <td class="column" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 33%;">
              <h4 style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">STEP ONE
              </h4>
              <p style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; ">You’ve got your savings
                <br />
                card ready to go.
              </p>              
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Or if you want to keep all 3 columns the same width in mobile then you can use the below code:

```css
     .column {
            float: left;
          }
    @media only screen and (max-width:600px){
            .column {
              float: none !important;
              width: 33% !important;
       display:inline-block;
              margin: 0px;
            }
    }
```

```html
    <!---- Steps Section ---->      
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="max-width: 600px; background-color:#ffffff;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="column" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 33%;">
                  <h4 style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">STEP ONE
                  </h4>
                  <p style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; ">You’ve got your savings
                    <br />
                    card ready to go.
                  </p>
                </td>
                <td class="column" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 33%;">
                  <h4 style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">STEP ONE
                  </h4>
                  <p style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; ">You’ve got your savings
                    <br />
                    card ready to go.
                  </p>              
                </td>
                <td class="column" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 33%;">
                  <h4 style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">STEP ONE
                  </h4>
                  <p style="color: #565A5C; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; ">You’ve got your savings
                    <br />
                    card ready to go.
                  </p>              
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Hope this is the answer you were after.

Comment: Thank you  - it ended up being an inline styling setting I needed to turn off in our ESP.